# Gathering a cached token via AqcuireTokenSilent fails

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a condition set to where if there's a cached token, it will use that or else it will either look for passed in credentials or prompt for credentials. Even after entering my credentials once via AcquireTokenInteractive() and running the program again, it still prompts for credentials. If I only have AcquireTokenSilent(), I get a reference error for the `token` variable because nothing is passed to it. It is either not caching my token or it is not fetching my cached token properly, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot either. According to the MSDocs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens it should do the caching automatically.

For the time being, I commented out the AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword() for troubleshooting purposes.

```
static async Task<GraphServiceClient> Auth()
        {

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string token = null;
            IPublicClientApplication app;
            app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"])
                  .Build();
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            if (accounts.Any())
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                                  .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    ///var securePassword = new SecureString();
                    ///foreach (char c in "dummy")        // you should fetch the password
                    ///    securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke

                    /// result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes,"joe@contoso.com",securePassword).ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException)
                {
                    ///
                }
                try
                {
                    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException)
                {
                    ///
                }
            }
            token = result.AccessToken;

            // Use the token

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                            async (requestMessage) =>
                            {
                                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                            }));
            return graphClient;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right. The SDK will do the caching automatically. I tested it by creating a console app:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string flag = "Y";

            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("60ef0838-f145-4f00-b7ba-a5af7f31cc3c").Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://4a673722-5437-4663-bba7-5f49372e06ba/Group.All","openid" };

            do
            {
                List<IAccount> list = app.GetAccountsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToList();

                Console.WriteLine("Checking cache");
                if (list.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Find {list.Count}");
                    list.ForEach(_ =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Acquire a new token for {_.Username}");
                        AuthenticationResult result = app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, _).WithForceRefresh(true).WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/").ExecuteAsync().Result;
                        Console.WriteLine($"New token -> {result.AccessToken}");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No cache");
                    try
                    {
                        var securePassword = new SecureString();

                        // Test AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword
                        foreach (char c in "**********") securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                        AuthenticationResult result = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, "jack@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com", securePassword).WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/").ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                        // Test AcquireTokenInteractive
                        //AuthenticationResult result = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/").ExecuteAsync().Result;
                        Console.WriteLine(result.Account.Username + " -> " + result.AccessToken);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        Console.Error.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    }
                }

                Console.Write("Continue? Y/N:");
                flag = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (flag.Trim().ToUpper().Equals("Y"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Odd, any idea why mine isn't caching properly?

Comment: Not pretty sure. But I see that in your Auth method, you were creating a new `PublicClientApplication` every time, there should be no existing account cache.